# How to receive feedback from users about the clearness of website UI?

Tags: user-interface, responsive-design

We are powering a big and popular website with many different teams working on making it happen. We have a separate UI design team who is polishing out the website and working hard on designing every element and interaction and the result looks great! However when my sister recently tried using the website, she bombarded me with a bunch of questions some of which were really basic.

We have a separate support team who is replying to support tickets and if they see a recurring issue, they go to dev or design teams and bring it up; however I am concerned that very few users will actually create a support ticket if they are struggling to find something and instead will just keep suffering and looking for the right button, etc..

I am wondering whether there is some technology or general approach to measure UI efficiency (perhaps some JS tool)? Ideally I want to be able to find answer to this question: if user wants to do X or find Y, is it clear for them how to do that or do most people struggle doing that?

I know this is a very general question but any clue on where I can start researching this would be highly appreciated!

Comment: This is probably better suited for ux.stackexchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to answer this question.

Ask your UI design team what they did to get feedback from people while they were designing it.  In doing so, you will understand the audience for which they designed your site, what their goals were, what challenges they faced along the way, what design tradeoffs they had to make to finish the design.  You should also ask if they already have a plan in place to evaluate the completed website and make ongoing changes.  If they do, your design team would probably appreciate your interest and willingness to help them get the information that they will need.

If your design team didn't gather feedback from people while they were designing it, share with them your concern.  (Although, keep in mind that your sister might not actually be their target audience.  It can be a perfectly valid design decision to assume some level of knowledge on the part of their audience, which your sister might or might not have.  If your sister's questions were very basic, it might simply mean that she's not the intended audience for your website.)  Tell them that you would like to do something to understand how usable your website is, and let them come up with solutions.

If you would like to go into your meeting with the design team prepared with some information, you could do a few things.  For example, if you have had tickets that you felt were related to the design, make sure to share those with the design team.  In a big organization, it's very easy for the design team never to see or have interaction with the support organization, and thus never hear about tickets like these.  Likewise, you could do some log analysis and determine if there is a particular page that seems problematic (say, a form that people would need to fill out, and that has a particularly high bounce rate).

Before implementing anything, make sure that your design team is involved and bought off.  Unless your design team either says that they don't have the time to be involved or are not interested in what you are doing, you should work closely with them to allow them to do their job, which is to deliver a great design that meets the needs of their audience.